# PHP script returns 403 Forbidden error when Content-Length is omitted

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I'm using a shared web hosting account on a Linux server. My server-side PHP script can be called from my Windows (client) application using [Windows sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Without showing too much code (which is a basic connection via HTTP protocol to port 80) the client application may send the following header to the PHP script:

```
POST 
/php/checkupdates.php?ver=1.2.3.4&ref=&nam=some%20name
 HTTP/1.0\r\n
Accept: text/plain, text/html, */*\r\n
Accept-Language: en-us\r\n
Accept-Encoding: deflate\r\n
User-Agent: My own agent\r\n
Host: 
mydomain.com
\r\n
\r\n
```

But for some reason this script returns the `403 Forbidden` error. Interestingly enough, if I load this same URL in a web browser, the PHP script runs just fine.

Purely by trial and error process I discovered that if I add the following line to the header my PHP script starts to work fine:

```
Content-Length: 0\r\n
```

Well, this is all good. But the issue is that to add this line I need to update all client (Windows) applications that my users have downloaded and been using for a while. In other words, it's not as easy to do.

So I was hoping to try to fix this from a server (i.e. PHP) side. Any ideas?

PS. I should also point out that this used to work when I hosted with a previous web hosting company (i.e. without the `Content-Length` line.)

PS2. I tried contacting my current web hosting provider but their tech support keep asking for my public IP. (Possibly to whitelist me so I don't see this error, which won't solve it for others.) In other words I'm not really sure that they know what they're doing. So I thought to understand it first before I contact them again.

Comment: Since you're sending a `POST`, the server has to know where the end of the posted parameters are. The `Content-Length` is required so it will know this.

Comment: @Barmar: I thought the double new-line, i.e. `\r\n\r\n` does it.

Comment: The double newline is the end of the headers, not the end of the post data. Maybe you should be using `GET` instead of `POST`, if you're not sending any parameters in the body.

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks. I see it now. But as I stated above, I'm looking for possible ways to resolve it from a server-side since changing client script is not as easy for me.

Comment: From [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4): For compatibility with HTTP/1.0 applications, HTTP/1.1 requests containing a message-body MUST include a valid Content-Length header field unless the server is known to be HTTP/1.1 compliant. If a request contains a message-body and a Content-Length is not given, the server SHOULD respond with 400 (bad request) if it cannot determine the length of the message, or with 411 (length required) if it wishes to insist on receiving a valid Content-Length.

Comment: The core of Apache does not insist that a POST has a body, but PHP must be.